# Backpack for Laravel 'phone' field not working

Tags: laravel-backpack

I am using Backpack for Laravel to create an admin panel, however I am unable to make the 'phone' field show up as it is in the [docs](https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/5.x/crud-fields#phone-pro).

I have the Pro version, everything is up to date:
LARAVEL VERSION:
v9.45.0

BACKPACK VERSION:
5.4.11

Here is the field definition in the controller:

```
CRUD::addField([
        'name' => 'telephone',
        'label' => 'Telephone',
        'type' => 'phone',
        'config' => [
            'onlyContries' => ['bd', 'cl', 'in', 'lv', 'pt', 'ro'],
            'initialCountry' => 'cl',
            'separateDialCode' => true,
            'nationalMode' => false,
            'autoHideDialCode' => false,
        ],
        'wrapper' => [
            'class' => 'col-md-4',
        ],
    ]);
```

The 'telephone' column in the database is varchar(20). I also tried with a phone column unsignedBigInt but it also resulted in the exact same behaviour.

Furthermore the above field does not go through the request validation, if that could be a hint as to what might be happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is probably some misconfiguration that is breaking the field on your side, as I've just tested and everything seems to be working:

[image]

Possible causes that I could think from the top of my head are:

1. Don't have the minimum required PRO version: `composer show backpack/pro` should give you the installed version, the minimum required for phone field is 1.4.
2. Need to re-publish backpack assets. `php artisan backpack:publish-assets`
3. Field is not in fillable property of the model and/or isn't a fake field.

Let me know if you were able to solve it.

Cheers

Comment: Thank you! Re-publishing the backpack assets was the issue in my case.